# Proving a version of the inequalities of averages using induction

Tags: inequality, induction

Let $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ positive numbers such that $x_1*x_2*\ldots*x_n=1\\$

Prove by induction that:

$x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n \ge n$

I have thought about dividing the lh side of the inequality by n, and then trying to use what was given to say that

$\frac{x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n+x_{n+1}}{n+1} \ge\sqrt[n]{x_1*x_2\ldots*x_{n+1}} \ge 1 $

Am i heading the right direction? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: are you forgetting the base case?

Comment: Given that you have to prove it by induction, the induction approach is pretty straightforward. Have you set that up as yet? If so, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lemma:** If the product of $n\geq 2$ positive reals is 1, then we can find one term that is $\leq 1$ and one term that is $\geq 1$.

Base case: Apply the lemma, so $(x_1 - 1)(x_2-1) \leq 0 \Rightarrow x_1 + x_2 \geq x_1 x_2 + 1 = 2$.

Induction step. Apply the lemma, WLOG let $x_n \leq 1, x_{n+1} \geq 1$.

Apply the induction hypothesis to the $n$ terms $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{n-1}, (x_nx_{n+1})$.
We have $ x_nx_{n+1} + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i   \geq n$.

It remains to show that $x_n +x_{n+1} - x_n x_{n+1} \geq 1$, which is $0 \geq (x_n -1 ) ( x_{n+1} -1 ) $, which is obviously true by our WLOG definition.

---

(On second thought, I can't push through the forward part, so... let me think about it ...)

**Hint:** The "hard" part is proving the base case, namely $x_1 \times x_2 = 1 \Rightarrow x_1 + x_2 \geq 2$.

**Hint:** For these "inequalities similar to the AM-GM style", [Forward Backward Induction](https://brilliant.org/wiki/forward-backwards-induction/) works wonders.

Comment: +1, however, the base case doesn't seem so hard to me: If $a,b\geq0$ with $a\cdot b=1$, then $$0\le(\sqrt a - \sqrt b)^2=a-2\sqrt{a\cdot b} +b=a+b-2$$ so $a+b\geq 2$.

Comment: Hence the use of quotation marks. It's not supposed to be bad. The forward backward induction is just a ton of the base cases (and a standard template). It doesn't require any additional theory, or tricks, or anything else. E.g. compare against the second approach, which needed a bit of creativity, though it ultimately still resolved to the base case.